# Use libraries inside injection DLL file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, libcurl, dll-injection

I'm working on the internal mod menu for one game and I want to use [CPR](https://whoshuu.github.io/cpr/#usage) library inside my DLL to get the latest version of offset from the server after injection. right now I get a static version of CPR package with vcpkg and move all .lib file and include file to my project and add them in my include and lib directories and use it like this :

```
#pragma once
#pragma comment(lib, "crypt32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "zlib.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "libcurl.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "cpr.lib")

#include "cpr/cpr.h"

cpr::Response r = cpr::Get(cpr::Url{ "https://myurl.com/getoffset" });
                    cout << r.status_code << endl;
                    cout << r.text << endl; 
string json= r.text;
```

It's work fine without any problem but as you can see it's a bit messy with all those "#pragma comment" so I tried to use a dynamic version of CPR so after compiling it I have 3 DLL files :

1. myMode.dll
2. libcurl.dll
3. zlib1.dll

the problem now is I must put "zlib1.dll" and "libcurl.dll" inside game folder near .exe file otherwise it won't inject; is there any way to locate them inside my DLL and tell DLL to use that location?

or just use it like this but remove this "#pragma comment" somehow and add the location for all of them in visual studio ?

Comment: "is there any way to locate them inside my DLL" that's what statically linking is, basically. Otherwise, no, not without extracting and writing to disk or creating a virtual drive

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need to know about DLL search paths is [well documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order).

The easiest approach would be to just statically link with libcurl and zlib instead of using the DLL stub libraries.  What's the downside of that?

Otherwise, all your dependent DLLs need to be in your EXE folder, the current working directory (usually the same as the EXE folder), a system directory (no!), or the PATH.

If your extension has an installer, then maybe it just updates PATH with your install folder of your DLL and all its dependencies.

As for the "messy" `pragma comment` statements. The standard approach is to add these via the Visual Studio project IDE. That gives you better control of the link search path so you don't have to dump all the stub .lib files in the same folder you build from.

Comment: thank you can you tell me how can manage them with Visual Studio?

Comment: Do you mean `lib` ？You could find and add them in `Properties->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories`, `Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories` and `Properties->Linker->Input->->Additional Dependencies`